# View didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instaed

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

I'm using `Django 1.11` and I'm trying to improve an existing code which let to export data to an Excel file. There are 2 cases :

- File contains less than 70.000 rows. In this way, user can directly download the generated output file.
- File contains more than 70.000 rows. In this case, the file is written in the media folder.

I'm getting an issue with the second part.

The file is well-written in the Media folder, but I don't find a way to provide an HttpResponse object.

In my HTML template, I have this link :

```
<a title="Export to Excel" class="button btn btn-default" href="{% url 'app:export-xls' model=model %}">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span>
</a>
```

In my view, I have this file :

```
class ExportAPP(View):

    def export_xls(self, model=""):
        app_label = 'app'

        # create a workbook in memory
        output = io.BytesIO()

        book = Workbook(output, {'constant_memory': True})
        sheet = book.add_worksheet('Page 1')
        # Sheet header, first row
        row_num = 0

        #Part which fill the file, adjust columns etc ..
        ...

        book.close()

        if len(rows) < 70000:
            # construct response
            output.seek(0)
            name = 'Obsolete' if obsolete else ''
            name += str(model._meta.verbose_name_plural)
            response = HttpResponse(output.read(),
                                content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + name + '.xlsx"'
            return response

        #The interesting part
        else:
            print('Export contains more than 70.000 entries')
            output.seek(0)
            name = 'Obsolete' if obsolete else ''
            name += str(model._meta.verbose_name_plural)

            name = name + "_" + str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%s")) + '.xlsx'
            file = default_storage.save(name, output)
```

I'm getting this issue :

`The view app.views.export.export_xls didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

I would like to return the same template page but I don't find a way to do that.

Comment: There's no `return response` in the `else` clause. So it returns `None`.

Comment: @nigel222 Yes I agree. But I don't know How I can return the template on which on I called the function.

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean by that. `return HttpResponseRedirect(...)` to the same view that served up the HTML at the top of your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is reaching `else` statement. You are not returning any response in else statement. It should be like this

```
else:
    print('Export contains more than 70.000 entries')
    output.seek(0)
    name = 'Obsolete' if obsolete else ''
    name += str(model._meta.verbose_name_plural)

    name = name + "_" + str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%s")) + '.xlsx'
    file = default_storage.save(name, output)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: Yes that's the way. But before to validate your answer, I just have a question. Before to export, I'm making a search which will be write in my file. I would like to get this page in the `HttpResponseRedirect` which looks like this : `http://localhost:8000/finalproduct/list/?mah=&releasing_body=&trade_name=&member_state=&pheur_name=&decision=&final_bulk_num=&domain=&manufacturer_name=&date_from=2018%2F10%2F18&name=&date_to=2019%2F02%2F12&eu_cert_n=&status=current&upstream_code_product=&certificate_nullified=both`. There is a way to return this url ?

Comment: `return redirect(reverse('finalproduct_list') + '?mah=&releasing_body=&trade_name=&member_state=&pheur_name=&decision=&final_bulk_num=&domain=&manufacturer_name=&date_from=2018%2F10%2F18&name=&date_to=2019%2F02%2F12&eu_cert_n=&status=current&upstream_code_product=&certificate_nullified=both')`

Comment: You have to create a URL first

Comment: @I used part of your answer to get a dynamical url.

Answer (score 0):

You should return something here, some page or code 200, or, maybe redirect to some page (return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')):

```
else:
            print('Export contains more than 70.000 entries')
            output.seek(0)
            name = 'Obsolete' if obsolete else ''
            name += str(model._meta.verbose_name_plural)

            name = name + "_" + str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%s")) + '.xlsx'
            file = default_storage.save(name, output)
```